# Adjust texview according to screen size to fit the content in proper scale

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

In my application, i am creating a date view using the below code. I have to create these date UI elements multiple times to make a calender like tabular UI. I am using GridLayoutManager and RecycleView to create the entire view which will look like a month.
When UI is loaded all the textviews in the UI still shows the big in big font. How i can shrink the text proportionally? Do i have to adjust the font programmatically or is there a way i can adjust the content to fit/scale accroding to available UI?

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.myApps.app1.calendarDayViewFragment">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
        tools:context="com.myApps.app1.monthDetailedDayViewFragment"
        android:id="@+id/layout_detailed_day_view">

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <!-- Section Row 2 -->
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/linear_layout_section_1">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="row_text_1_1"
                    android:textAlignment="textStart"
                    android:id="@+id/textView_day_information_row_1_1"
                    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="row_text_1_2"
                    android:id="@+id/textView_day_information_row_1_2"
                    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Section Row 2 -->
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_section_2" >

            <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/linear_layout_section_2_1"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <!-- Next to Big TEXT, row 1 -->
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Section_2_text_row_1"
                    android:textAlignment="textStart"
                    android:id="@+id/textView_day_information1"
                    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

                <!-- Next to Big TEXT, row 2 -->
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Section_2_text_row_2"
                    android:textAlignment="textStart"
                    android:id="@+id/textView_day_information2"
                    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

                <!-- Next to Big TEXT, row 3 -->
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Section_2_text_row_3"
                    android:textAlignment="textStart"
                    android:id="@+id/textView_day_information3"
                    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

                <!-- Next to Big TEXT, row 4 -->
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Section_2_text_row_4"
                    android:textAlignment="textStart"
                    android:id="@+id/textView_day_information4"
                    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

                <!-- Next to Big TEXT, row 5 -->
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Section_2_text_row_5"
                    android:textAlignment="textStart"
                    android:id="@+id/textView_day_information5"
                    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/linear_layout_section_2_2"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <!-- Big Text -->
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="१०"
                    android:id="@+id/calendar_day_header"
                    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                    android:textSize="140dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:gravity="right" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Section Row 3 -->
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_section_3">

            <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/linear_layout_section_3_1">
                <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="text_row_3_1"
                android:id="@+id/textView_information_row_3_1"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
                <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="text_row_3_2"
                android:id="@+id/textView_information_row_3_2"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
            </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_section_3_2">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp" android:src="@drawable/ic_image1"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_gravity="right"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Here is the RecycleView code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:id="@+id/recyclerview_mothly_dates"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:scrollbars="vertical"
                            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light" >

                        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Thanks,
IamHuM

Answer (score 0):

create multiple folder for values like this and paste dimens.xml in each folder and manage Text Size from here same name with different values.

```
values
values-xhdpi
values-xxhdpi
values-xxxhdpi
values-sw600dp
values-sw800dp
```

`<TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="१०"
                        android:id="@+id/calendar_day_header"
                        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/test_140_size"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:gravity="right" />`

NOTE: Give different value  of Text size in sp according to resolution in each dimens.xml file with same name.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this library to your gradle file
 [**compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.3'**](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)

All you need to do is: add  **android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp"**

You have to use **sdp** instead of **dp**, this will automatically scale your textView or any other View according to the dimension that is required by any device irrespective of its size.

hope this solves your problem.

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/profile_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp" />
```